# Problems sending bulk iOS notifications

Tags: java, ios, push-notification, payload

I'm having problems sending bulk notifications for iOS devices, when I send out a few devices (1-20 more or less) it works without problems, but when I have to send a bulk send (3000+) it is giving me the following error:

> [2017-04-27 15:12:07] ERROR (Notificaciones:347) - IOS: Error en envio
>   notificaciones - CommunicationException: 
>   javapns.communication.exceptions.CommunicationException: Communication
>   exception: java.net.ConnectException: Expir tiempo de
>   conexiConnection timed out)     at
>   javapns.communication.ConnectionToAppleServer.getSSLSocket(ConnectionToAppleServer.java:156)
>     at
>   javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.initializeConnection(PushNotificationManager.java:106)
>     at
>   javapns.notification.transmission.NotificationThread.runList(NotificationThread.java:215)
>     at
>   javapns.notification.transmission.NotificationThread.run(NotificationThread.java:199)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Expir tiempo de conexiConnection timed
>   out)  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:576)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:635)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.(SSLSocketImpl.java:423)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
>     at
>   javapns.communication.ConnectionToAppleServer.getSSLSocket(ConnectionToAppleServer.java:153)
>     ... 4 more

My code is the following:

```
private static  void realizaEnvioIOSLista (final List<DispositivoDto> dispositivos, final String textoES, final String textoCA, final String textoEN, final String tipoNotificacion){       

        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){              
                try {           
                    final List<String> idsDispositivos = new ArrayList<String>();                   

                    final String keystore = XmlUtils.dirCertIOS + XmlUtils.nomCertificado;
                    final String password = XmlUtils.password;
                    final boolean production = XmlUtils.production;

                    //Obtenemos los ids de los dispositivos
                    for(DispositivoDto r : dispositivos)
                         idsDispositivos.add(r.getIdDispositivo());                  

                    PushNotificationPayload payload = PushNotificationBigPayload.complex();

                    /* Customize the payload */ 
                    payload.addAlert(textoES);    
//                  payload.addSound('default');
                    payload.setContentAvailable(true);

                    payload.addCustomDictionary("es", textoES);
                    payload.addCustomDictionary("en", textoCA);
                    payload.addCustomDictionary("ca", textoEN);
                    payload.addCustomDictionary("tiponotificacion", tipoNotificacion);  

                    List<PushedNotification> notifications = new ArrayList<PushedNotification>();

                    if(idsDispositivos.size()<= 200){   
                        notifications = Push.payload(payload, keystore, password, production, idsDispositivos);

                    } else {
                        int threads = 1;

                        if(dispositivos.size() > 200) {
                            threads = (int) Math.ceil(dispositivos.size()/200);
                        }

                        notifications = Push.payload(payload, keystore, password, production, threads, idsDispositivos);  
                    }

                    int dispEliminados = 0;
                    int dispNotificados = 0;

                    for (PushedNotification notification : notifications) {
                        if (notification.isSuccessful()) {
                            dispNotificados ++;
                        } else {
                            String invalidToken = notification.getDevice().getToken();

                            int index = idsDispositivos.indexOf(invalidToken);

                            Integer usuario = dispositivos.get(index).getUsuario();
                            String idHardware = dispositivos.get(index).getIdHardwareDis();

                            aBD.unregisterDispositivo(usuario, invalidToken,idHardware);
                            dispEliminados ++;

        //                  Exception theProblem = notification.getException();
        //                  theProblem.printStackTrace();

                            //If the problem was an error-response packet returned by Apple, get it
                            ResponsePacket theErrorResponse = notification.getResponse();

                            if (theErrorResponse != null){
                                logNot.info("IOS: " +theErrorResponse.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }   
                    logNot.info("IOS: Dispositivos Notificados correctamente: " + dispNotificados);
                    logNot.info("IOS: Dispositivos Eliminados: " +dispEliminados);

                } catch (CommunicationException e) {
                    logNot.error("IOS: Error en envio notificaciones - CommunicationException: ",e);
                } catch (KeystoreException e) {
                    logNot.error("IOS: Error en envio notificaciones - KeystoreException: ",e);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    logNot.error("IOS: Error en envio notificaciones - JSONException: ",e);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logNot.error("IOS: Error en envio notificaciones",e);
                }
            }
        };

        thread.start();
    }
```

something wrong? What is the maximum number of devices and connections to the Apple server can be made? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, the code works fine, after talking with the system administrators we could see that it was a problem of configuration of the servers, since according to this link of [apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203609) to be able to send of notifications, the following must be taken into consideration:

> To use Apple Push Notification service (APNs), your Mac and iOS
>   clients need a direct and persistent connection to Apple's servers.

So that:

> If you use Wi-Fi behind a firewall, or private Access Point Name for
>   cellular data, connect to specific ports. You need a direct, unproxied
>   connection to the APNs servers on these ports:
>
> - TCP port 5223 to communicate with APNs.
> - TCP port 2195 to send notifications to APNs.
> - TCP port 2196 for the APNs feedback service.
> - TCP port 443 is required during device activation, and afterwards for fallback (on Wi-Fi only) if devices can't reach APNs on port 5223.

Moreover:

> The APNs servers use load balancing, so your devices don't always
>   connect to the same public IP address for notifications. It's best to
>   let your device access these ports on the entire 17.0.0.0/8 address
>   block, which is assigned to Apple.

So everything has been resolved by configuring the firewall, by the system administrators, to allow these connections. I hope it helps someone.